# Get results with multiple criterias

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have these tables
[image]

I want to get all matches for a concrete matchday along with bets for each match if its made by a concrete user. Basically avoid getting results from other users but still get all matches for the matchday. I tried `WHERE match.matchday = 1 AND user.userId = 1` but this gives only the results where both the matchday and the userId match, so if there is no bet on a match from the user for the matchday it is not added to the results

The result should be like

[image]

Also I am open for suggestions if this is a good way to get what I want, or I should just use multiple requests to get the data and manage it in the application

Comment: "I tried playing with the joins but couldn't get the result I want" Please edit your question with an example of this query. You should be able to add `AND user.userId = 1` to the `WHERE` clause of your query. So you'll probably have `WHERE match.matchday = 1 AND user.userId = 1`

Comment: Post the code that you used and got wrong results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM match
LEFT JOIN bet ON match.matchId = bet.matchId
WHERE  bet.userId = 1 AND match.matchday = 1`. This returns only the first 4 rows, matches with id 5 and 6 are not in the result because of course it fails to match the 1st clause of WHERE, where the userId should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it with small tweaks.

Here are 2 working solutions.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM match 
LEFT JOIN bet ON match.matchId = bet.matchId AND bet.userId = 1
LEFT JOIN user ON bet.userId = user.userId
WHERE match.matchday = 1
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM match 
LEFT JOIN bet ON match.matchId = bet.matchId
LEFT JOIN user ON bet.userId = user.userId
WHERE match.matchday = 1 AND (
    bet.userId = 1 OR bet.userId IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you SQL master :)